# Special Character in Visual Studio Code

Tags: character

How to solve this in Visual Studio Code. The document was created in notepad, it's perfect. See Image.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRUNz.png)

Have a nice day!

Comment: what have you try?

Answer (score 3):

It's solved. In notepad I saved unicode format.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuYYg.png)

Thank you guys!