# Editor does not recognize some characters

Tags: visual-studio-code, notepad++

When I open a cobol file in *Notepad++* it looks normal. However, in *Visual Studio Code* it looks weird like it does not recognize the characters in it. How can I make it so that it looks normal in *Visual Studio Code* also.
Here is how it looks in both.

Notepad++
[image: notepad++ image]

Visual Studio Code
[image]

Comment: Check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938297/special-character-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Special Character in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938297/special-character-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably saved in an encoding besides UTF-8. You can change the encoding with the "Change File Encoding" command, or by clicking on the encoding in the status bar. Or, try setting `"files.autoGuessEncoding": true`.

Answer (score 0):

Put a call to the built-in input function
at the very bottom of the script in 3.X (in 2.X use the name raw_input instead). For example:

import sys # Load a library module
print(sys.platform)
input() # <== ADDED

input reads and returns the next line of standard input, waiting if there is none yet available. The net effect in this context will be to pause the script, thereby keeping the output window open until you press the Enter key